# Implementing SSO return a Blank view

Tags: ios, facebook

I'm trying to implement SSO following the Tutorial:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/

At the end of Step 3, I'm supposed to Test my App running it on Simulator. The Run succeeded but all I see is a Blank View (screen). I'm not sure if I need to create the view called "authorization dialog" including the FB logo, buttons, etc or if it's automatically created by code I've implemented using Facebook SDK.

Also, I'm using a storyboard and wonder if that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's because you have once signed in and now you haven't logged out so it is already authorized and hence you cannot see anything :)

Answer (score 0):

Is your initial ViewController blankView ? Because the SSO only validates/autorize the session, you need to implement the UI in your ViewController.

Answer (score 0):

If you implement it in Storyboard I suggest you to do most of the code in your controller file, since I was stucked there for quite long time. But make sure to put this code in the app delegate file.

```
 #pragma mark Facebook

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    return [self.facebook handleOpenURL:url];
 }

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:   (NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [self.facebook handleOpenURL:url];
 }
```

Also in the delegate file you should instantiate the Facebook object before you use the in the above methods.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    viewController *controller = [[viewController alloc] init];
    // Initialize Facebook
    facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"Your app ID in string" andDelegate:controller];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```